# How to display seleced option in yii dropdown?

Tags: php, yii

I created a drop-down to select the category for search. When I search the product for example I search Shoes for MEN, when the view page loaded the item resets to default

I want the category to remain what I selected

```
  <form action="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/search" method="GET"  class="form-inline form-section-2 row  fadeInDown animated">
  <div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
  <input type="text"  name="loc"  class="form-control" id="loc" value="<?php  echo $locationdet ; ?>" placeholder="Enter Your Keyword">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 form-group" >
     <select  name="cat" class="form-control selectpicker">
        <option>Select Category</option>
        <option value = '0'>Men</option>
        <option value = '1'>Women</option>          
    </select> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-new">Search Products</button>    
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: are you trying to make something new `method="GET"` here `<select  name="cat" class="form-control selectpicker" method="GET">`

Comment: No..Thats my mistake..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<option value = '0' <?php if(isset($_GET['cat']) && $_GET['cat'] == '0') echo "selected" ?>>Men</option>
<option value = '1' <?php if(isset($_GET['cat']) && $_GET['cat'] == '1') echo "selected" ?>>Women</option>
```

Comment: Thank you for your simple method

Answer (score 1):

use

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('cat',isset( $_REQUEST['cat'] ) ? $_REQUEST['cat'] : NULL, array('0'=>'Men', '1'=>'Women'),
array('empty'=>'Select Category', 'class' => 'form-control selectpicker'));
```

to achieve yii style,

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass the selected option via the controller back to the view.

In the controller you will need something like this:

```
$this->render('viewName', array('name' => 'valueOfTheList'))
```

Then in the view you can use

```
<option value = '0' <?php if($name == '0') echo "selected" ?>>Men</option>
<option value = '1' <?php if($name == '1') echo "selected" ?>>Women</option>
```

However. Since you are using Yii. I would advise you to look at [CHTML::dropDownList()](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/#hh5). Then you could do something like

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('name', $select, 
          array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female'));
```

Which is really a more Yii way to approach these kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

**Yii way to implement this functionality.**

You can keep the form state by setting the user input value to Model properties. For this, you can use `CFormModel` to implement, same like YII's default login page. Below is a sample example.

1. Create a form model for your search (SearchForm.php) and place this inside `models` folder.

   ```
   class SearchForm extends CFormModel
   {
           public $search_key;
           public $search_cat;

           public function rules()
           {
                   return array(           
                           array('search_key,search_cat', 'required'),
                   );
           }
   }
   ```
2. Assume i am using `SiteController`. I want to show this search form in my index page. When i submit the form it will submitted to `search` action

   ```
    class SiteController extends Controller
    {
       public function actionIndex()
       {
           $searchModel=new SearchForm();
           $searchModel->search_key;
           $searchModel->search_cat;
           $this->render('index',array('searchModel'=>$searchModel));
       }

       public function actionSearch()
       {
             $searchModel=new SearchForm();
             if($_POST['SearchForm'])
             {
                $searchModel->attributes=$_POST['SearchForm'];
             }
             $this->render('search',array('searchModel'=>$searchModel));
       }
   ```

   }

`$searchModel->attributes=$_POST['SearchForm'];` That is i am resetting the user inputs to model.So, in your view the form will appear with user input values.

3. Call this Form in views

   ```
          <?php
       $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
           'id' => 'search-form',
           'enableClientValidation' => true,
           'action'=>array('default/search'), //Submiting my form to Search action
          ));
       ?>

               <?php echo $form->textField($searchModel, 'search_key'); ?>    
               <?php
               $htmlOptions = array('size' => '1', 'prompt' => 'Select'); 
               $list = array('0' => 'Men', '1' => 'Women'); // You can load your Categories from the Database table/Model.
               echo $form->dropDownList($searchModel, 'search_cat', $list, $htmlOptions);
               ?>
               <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Search'); ?>
       <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
   ```

Hope, This will help you for your better practice.